# Python - Script compatible by with which version?

Tags: python

Is there a way to determine what version of python is a particular script compatible with ?

I know this sounds like a stupid question but I have Python scripts from different sources. I have to manually run each script with the Python versions that I have installed on my system to check which version they are compatible with so was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What happens when they are compatible with both versions? :-)

Comment: That would be the ideal case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a bash script to run all python script.If there is error occurs, it thinks the script is incompatible with Python2/3.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=$(ls ./*.py)

for item in ${dirs}
do
    python2 ${item} > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "${item} is a python2 script" && continue
    python3 ${item} > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "${item} is a python3 script" && continue
    echo "There is an error on your ${item}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `2to3` on something and there are no corrections then it is at least python 3 compatible. Additionally, if you run `pip install 3to2` and then run `3to2` and there are no corrections then said file is python 2 compatible.